# Best salting rule in bcrypt algorithm

Tags: java, security, bcrypt

I am trying to generate signature token for distributed environment with java bcrypt algorithm,I want my token to be salted by some random string, just wanted suggestion about what can be the best way to create salt in this case so that I can retrieve my original string easily in other end.I started my implementation with sessionid, but sessionid wont be strong salt

Comment: Random is only requirement for a salt. What's the issue with your session ID? Why not use SecureRandom class to generate random bytes?

Comment: @Marcus Adams: The salt should not be known by the client and the sessionId can be found in a cookie client side (or in the url if cookies are disabled)

Comment: I would also simply use a SecureRandom and store in the clients session serverside.

Comment: @tom, its ok to go with storing it in session, but my scenario is different in which two servers are talking through URL redirect thus the session of one server is different from that of other,what I am actually trying to do is a SSO(Single Sign Out), with some way that I am able to validate the token signature in other server without communicating with the server which generated the number or storing it in database.

Comment: @tom, a salt is no good without a password hash, and if they have the password hash, they have the salt.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please explain what you mean by a "signature token" (what is being signed?) and what you want to use BCrypt for (it isn't a signature algorithm)? What is the "original string" that you want to retrieve (BCrypt isn't invertible)?

Comment: Yes its means data is being signed. and I don't want to invert it, but it should be such strong that no one can invert it, but I have the specific key on the other end such that same hash can be generated from data.